# Children's book about the dangers of pollution

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this book around the 3rd or 4th grade and I *thought* that it was written and illustrated by Chris Van Allsburg, but looking at his bibliography, I can't find the title.

The plot, if I remember correctly, is about this kid (I think a boy) who doesn't know what he wants for his birthday, and all he wants is toys or something, but he goes to bed and he is transported into a levelled forest (I think he and his bed were at the top of one of the last trees of the forest). He sees a bunch of foresters and they explain the forest is being cut down for commercial reasons.

He's then transported to the middle of the sea where he sees a captain and his fishing crew cheering and really excited over a really small fish they caught. The boy is confused and asks why they're so excited over such a small fish, and the captain explains that the oceans are so barren that it has been months since they last caught a fish.

I think he makes a few more trips and ends up back in his room and he decides for his birthday he wants to plant a tree in his backyard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns of it **was** Chris Van Allsburg, his Wikipedia entry didn't have a link to the book in his bibliography.

[Just A Dream](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0547520263)

Comment: I know this is the older question and answer, but the other one has more details.